# Windows Internet Connection sharing with Mobile Broadband

Tags: windows-7, ics, mobile-broadband

Due to circumstances, I have only got mobile broadband where I am living.  I have a small network with a ADSL Router (but which isn't connected to the Internet.  I want to use ICS to allow one machine (with the MBB modem) to act as the Internet interface and allow other machines connected to the ADSL router (including a new Android tablet by WiFi) to use the single mobile broadband connection.

I've a feeling that my configuration is not valid - as it stands, but I'm not sure.

Can some kind soul lead me "by the nose" to getting this working?

FWIW The mahcines are all running Windows 7

TIA,
Paolo

Comment: `Due to circumstances` ... and because of reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I decided to go with a PocketWiFi modem/router.  I bought it outright (no plan) and popped the SIM I was already using into it.  At less than AU$80 it provided a much more versatile solution.

Thanks anyway!
Paolo

Answer (score 1):

Use this software on your PC that has mobile broadband, it will turn it into a wireless Hotspot for other PC's. No router needed.

http://connectify.me/

Comment: This provides a partial solution and I use it when at other locations and circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Might be easier to cut out the middle man (the router) and just share the internet connection directly through the machine with the stick, using an Ad-Hoc network.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Using-ICS-Internet-Connection-Sharing

Comment: Ahh sorry, that was for Vista, try this one: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Using-ICS-Internet-Connection-Sharing

Comment: This thread may also help, though I haven't read it fully: http://windows7forums.com/windows-7-networking/1037-ad-hoc-internet-connection-sharing.html